# htaccess - optional url parameter for redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a redirect for an url in my htaccess file that works just like it should:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html$ view.php?mode=$1&id=$2 [nc]
```

However when I modify the line to try to check for the existence of the start parameter (`?start=1`) with the line below, I get a 404.

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html(\?start=[0-9]+)$ view.php?mode=$1&id=$2&start=$5 [nc]
```

How should I write this to obtain the optional `start` parameter and add it to the URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a `RewriteRule`, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` in a `RewriteCond` and use the **%N** to backreference grouping:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html$ view.php?mode=$1&id=$2&start=%1 [nc]
```

But, you don't need to do this. To append an existing query string just use the `QSA flag`:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html$ view.php?mode=$1&id=$2 [nc,QSA]
```

And if the URI is `/something/file.html?start=100`, it'll be rewritten to `/view.php?mode=something&id=file&start=100`